# What do these short white strips mean on Japanese roads?

Tags: japan, driving, road-signs

I see these signs mean on Japanese roads on https://youtu.be/15wVVByNgJY?t=3640:

[image]

I'm referring to these short white strips:

[image]

https://www.police.pref.kanagawa.jp/eng/e_mes/engf1008.htm doesn't contain that case.

Comment: The dashed lines end when the road the video is on joins with the parallel lanes on the right hand side.  They're probably indications of this happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those lines are used before/on curves, as well as straightaways that should be taken at slower speeds, to help slow down the driver. By having dotted lines, it makes the drivers feel they are going too fast and makes the lanes feel more cramped, coercing them to slow down.

There is no defined rule on this, which is why you can't find information on official sites. It's something each prefecture adds on their discretion.

I've confirmed these by looking through some driving sites. ([Here](https://trafficnews.jp/post/87323) and [here](https://www.omoide-garage.com/column/car-life/centerline-type-role/))

Comment: "By having dotted lines, it makes the drivers feel they are going too fast".  Clever, I wonder if that supported by some studies.

Comment: Yes, I have seen quotes from such studies.

Comment: Certainly there will be a greater sense of motion from a dashed line than from an unbroken line. In UK they use bands of yellow lines *across* the lane at a descreasing separation to cause drivers to slow down, such as [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@53.337838,-1.9795343,3a,75y,315h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sl2kozKboyyaC2WgF3sVFuA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en).

Comment: This seems to fit in with my observation about where the markings end at the road juncture.

Comment: The UK also uses zigzag lines instead of straight lines to convey a sense of unease and heightened alertness around pedestrian crossings; very much the same as the dotted lines in the question.